# Java code not working properly-- working on odd summation

Tags: java

I am very new to Computer Science. I am trying to learn Java on my own for fun. I found some practice problems online and have gotten stuck. I am trying to write a simple loop to determine odd numbers. I want the loop to add one odd number at a time and then to sum the total. For example I want the program to display the numbers like A1 = {1}, A2 = {1, 3}, A3 = {1, 3, 5}, A4 = {1, 3, 5, 7}... where each A# adds on an additional odd number each time through the loop and then I also want to determine the total sum of all the list from A1 to A20. The sum should be as such. {1)+{1,3},+{1,3,5}=14

```
public class MyClass {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        int limit = 20;
        int sum = 0;
        for (int i = 1; i <= limit; i++) {

            // if the number is not divisible by 2 then it is odd
            if (i % 2 != 0) {
                System.out.print(i + " ");

            }
        }
    }
}
```

The code above displays odd numbers all together not the way I am hoping for. It also does not sum up the odd numbers.

Any help would be appreciated, thank you.

Comment: After initializing your `sum` you never use it...

Comment: Why not just do `i += 2` and dispense with checking whether it's odd or not?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Think about what you need to do: You have one loop that goes up to a limit, and every time you are executing a loop, you want to print all of the odd numbers up to your loop counter(in your case, `i`).

To determine all the odd numbers up to `i`, an easy way is to add another loop like so:

`for (int j = 1; j<=i; j+=2) {...}`. In this loop, you would both print that number, and add it to your sum counter (`sum += j`).

For console clarity, make sure to print an empty line after that loop. Hope that helps without giving it away completely

Comment: Thank you for the tip. I was able to figure out the rest of the code with the second loop in place.

Answer (score -2):

Try this code and compare it with yours. See the logic and patterns.
`

```
                if( i % 2 != 0){ 
                System.out.println(i + " ");
                sum = sum + i;
               }
        System.out.println("The sum is : 
    " +sum);

     }
    } 
   }    `
```